# Table of Contents Font Size Change

Tags: table-of-contents, fontsize

I am in the final stages of writing my dissertation and right now, I am trying to make my dissertation to match the graduate school standards. One of the issues that I am currently struggling with is the way the Table of Contents and List of Figures of my dissertation look like. For some reason, the font size of these two parts is larger than the rest of my document. I know similar questions have been asked on here but the proposed solutions don't seem to help my case. I have two questions:

**First Question** How can I change the font size of the Table of Contents title, *i.e.*, the term "Table of Contents"? (Similar question for List of Figures too)

I have to add that for this question, I found the term "Table of Contents" in the style file and tried to insert a `\small` term in front of it. This changes the font size but it prints the title as `=Table of Contents` and I am not sure how to remove to equal sign.

**Second Question** How can I change the font size of the entries of the Table of Contents and List of Figures sections?

I have put the Style file here for you to see: http://pastebin.com/2NP9Jbci

Answer (score 11):

Well, it seems that the class uses the internal ToC generator, therefore this should work:

```
\documentclass{report}

% THESE COUPLE LINES ARE THAT YOU NEED FOR THE 2ND PART
\AtBeginDocument{
  \addtocontents{toc}{\tiny}
  \addtocontents{lof}{\tiny}
}

% THESE COUPLE LINES ARE THAT YOU NEED FOR THE 1ST PART
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\tableofcontents}{\contentsname \@mkboth}{\small\contentsname \@mkboth}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\listoffigures}{\chapter *{\listfigurename }}{\chapter *{\small\listfigurename }}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures

\chapter{CHAPTER}
\section{SECTION}
\begin{figure} \caption{MY FIG} \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi tohecz, I managed to edit the style file itself to make the changes I want. Thanks for your input. One more question: Currently, my chapters have the following heading: CHAPTER X \\ CHAPTER NAME. The font of both line is the same size. Do you know a quick way that I can make the CHAPTER X become smaller?

Answer (score -1):

Here's an example *without* the package `babel`.

```
\documentclass[
12pt
]{report}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{
\Large % Change font size to whatever you want.
Table Of Contents % Change TOC title to whatever you want.
}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xurl}
 \usepackage[
 hidelinks
 ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\large % Change font size to whatever you want.
\tableofcontents
\normalsize

\section*{1. Section Title}

\label{s1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{s1}}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Here's an example *with* the package `babel`.

```
\documentclass[
12pt
]{report}

\usepackage[
vietnamese,
english
]{babel}
 \addto\captionsenglish{
 \renewcommand{\contentsname}{
 \Large % Change font size to whatever you want.
 Table Of Contents % Change TOC title to whatever you want.
 }}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xurl}
 \usepackage[
 hidelinks
 ]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\large % Change font size to whatever you want.
\tableofcontents
\normalsize

\section*{1. Section Title}

\label{s1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\nameref{s1}}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your suggestion modifies the font size of `\contentsname` everywhere, not just inside the TOC.

Comment: @VincentKrebs : OP didn't say he needs the size of `\contentsname` to _only_ change within the TOC, and nowhere else.